# How to declare a member functions as const or not depending on whether a template parameter is const or not

Tags: c++17

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct A {
  A(T a) : _value{a} {}
  T& value() {return _value;}
// if (std::is_const<Tp>) T& value() const {return _value;}
private:
  T _value;
};
int main() {
  A<int> mutA{1};
  cout << "mutA: " << mutA.value() << endl;
  mutA.value() += 10;
  cout << "mutA: " << mutA.value() << endl;
  A<const int> immA{2};
  cout << "immA: " << immA.value() << endl;
  // error immA.value() += 10;
}
```

`A` is intended to be instantiated with either: -

`A<int> mutableA{1};`

or

`A<const int> immutableA{1};`

What I would like to achieve, is that if the template parameter `Tp` is `const` (i.e. `std::is_const<Tp>::value` is true), then the member function `T& value()` would be declared as `T& value() const`;

The code below fails but something that is equivalent would be good: -

```cpp
if constexpr (std::is_const<Tp>::value) {
  T& value() {return _value;}
}
else {
  T& value() const {return _value;}
}
```

`A` has many functions so defining it twice would not be a solution.

Comment: For the specific case of returning a `T&`, I don't see why you need this. If `T` is `const`, then there is nothing a user can do with that return value to modify it. So even though `value()` is non-`const`, its return value is `const`. And if you had some function that modifies the value internally, that will also fail to compile if people call it. So why exactly do you need this?

Comment: There is `noexcept(expr)`, but there is no such thing for `const`, like `void foo() const(is_const_v<T>)`.

Comment: @NicolBolas, If you have a const pointer to A then value() needs to be const otherwise you can't call it. In a complex set of templated structs it can often be the case that you don't know if a pointer to A is const or not. This is orthogonal to whether T itself is const or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually worked out how to do this using std::enable_if.

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct A {
  A(T a) : _value{a} {}
  template <typename Tp = T>
  std::enable_if_t<std::is_const<Tp>::value, T&> value() const {return _value;}
  template <typename Tp = T>
  std::enable_if_t<!std::is_const<Tp>::value, T&> value() {return _value;}
private:
  T _value;
};
```

This works because of "Substitution Failure Is Not An Error ([SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae))." Note that you can't use the template parameter T directly, as a substitution must occur for SFINAE to work. Supplying a default parameter, as in `template <typename Tp = T>`, does the trick.

If the condition to `std::enable_if_t` is false then the function will not be declared. If it is true then the second parameter, `T&` in this case, is the result of `std::enable_if_t`.

`std::enable_if_t` is only available from C++14 onwards. If you are using C++11 you will have to use the slightly more verbose form `typename std::enable_if<std::is_const<Tp>::value, T&>::type`.

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct A {
  A(T a) : _value{a} {}
  template <typename Tp = T>
  typename std::enable_if<std::is_const<Tp>::value, T&>::type value() const {return _value;}
  template <typename Tp = T>
  typename std::enable_if<!std::is_const<Tp>::value, T&>::type value() {return _value;}
private:
  T _value;
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't allow `const A<int> a(3); int n = a.value();`.

Answer (score 1):

Just declare both, but making sure the `const` version only allows `const` access:

```
template <typename T>
struct A {
  A(T a) : _value{a} {}
  T& value() {return _value;}
  const T& value() const {return _value;}
private:
  T _value;
};
```

Looking at the use cases:

```
void show(int);
void modify(int&);

void f1(A<int>& a) {
    show(a.value());
    modify(a.value());
}
```

Okay, `a.value()` returns `int&` here, so the variable can be modified.

```
void f2(A<const int>& a) {
    show(a.value());
    // modify(a.value()); // invalid
}
```

Here even though we're calling `T& value();`, since `T` is `const int` the return type is `const int&`, and the value can't be modified.

```
void f3(const A<int>& a) {
    show(a.value());
    // modify(a.value()); // invalid
}
```

Now we're calling `const T& value() const`;, so the return type is `const int&`. Again the value can't be modified.

```
void f4(const A<const int>& a) {
    show(a.value());
    // modify(a.value()); // invalid
}
```

This one also calls `const T& value() const`. With `T=const int`, the language "collapses" the redundant `const`, so that `const T` is the same as `const int`, and the return type is `const int&`. So the value can't be modified.